# How to validate email and password while login in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I just started learning nodejs now, I wrote api for login, I encrypted password by using bcrypt npm. Now I want to validate email and password. Logic should be like this: only registered users are eligible to log in, and given password should also match. This password must be same when he or she  registered.

These two conditions want to match other it have show error messages in console like this If the email address is wrong it has to show "User not found".  If he entered a wrong password, then it has to show, "Please enter a valid password".  If both are correct, it has to show User logged successfully.

If I am not clear with my doubt please put a comment.

This is login Api:

```
app.post("/api/login", async (req, res) => {
  // console.log(req.body)

  const loginInfo = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  };

  // console.log(loginInfo)

  const log = Login.find(
    { email: req.body.email },
    { password: req.body.password }
  );

  console.log(log);

  if (email == email && password == password) {
    console.log(loggedsucessfully);
  } else {
    console.log(invalidlogin);
  }

  const hash = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltRounds);
  req.body.password = hash;
  // console.log(req.body)

  const loggedUsers = new Login(req.body);

  try {
    const result = await loggedUsers.save();
    res.json(result);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: "sorry something went wrong" });
  }
});
```

These are the npms I installed:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
require('./models/db');
const Jobs = require('./models/job');
const Users = require('./models/user')
const Login = require('./models/login')
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

This is database db.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/jobsdb", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected");
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

This is schema login.js

```
const mongoose = require(`mongoose`);

const loginSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true, trim: true }
});

const Login = mongoose.model("login", loginSchema);
module.exports = Login;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to find the user with the given email.
If the user is not falsy, then we need to compare the password given with the found user's password. If it is equal, login is successfull.

You can use the following route:

```
router.post("/api/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    let user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (!user) return res.status(400).send("User not found");

    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!validPassword) return res.status(400).send("Please enter a valid password.");

    //at this point, login is successfull, return the user info without the password info
    user.password = undefined;

    res.send(user);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on [medium](https://medium.com/quick-code/handling-authentication-and-authorization-with-node-7f9548fedde8). You can write a function 'validate' and check the email before searching in your DB.

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

function validateUser(user) {
  const schema = {
    name: Joi.string().min(3).max(50).required(),
    email: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required().email(),
    password: Joi.string().min(3).max(255).required()
  };

  return Joi.validate(user, schema);
}
app.post('/api/login', async (req, res) => {
   const { error } = validateUser(req.body);
   if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using method in schema model 
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods

For example, if you want to validate password add a method `validPassword`

```
loginSchema.methods.validPassword = function( pwd ) {
    return ( this.password === pwd );
};
```

Then

```
   loginSchema.findOne({ password: req.body.password }, function (err, login) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!login) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect login.' });
        }
        if (!login.validPassword(password)) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
        }
        return done(null, login);
    });
```